# Handling a #Num! Error on importing Excel into Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, ado, ms-access-2003

I'm importing a spreadsheet from Excel 2003 to Access 2003 using ADO (`Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"`). However, I've got some text entries in a date field. These come through as `#Num!` values, as you might expect.

What I'd like to do is wrap the offending fields in something like `IIf(IsDate(FIELDNAME),FIELDNAME,#1/1/1900#)`. However, this still results in `#Num!`. So does testing `IsDate()`, `IsDate(CVar())`, `IsError()`, `IsError(CDat())`, and `VBAFunctionThatReturns0GivenAnyValue(FIELDNAME)`.

Anyone have any idea of a wrapper function I can use that'll do the job? I'm more or less at my wit's end?

Please note: I don't have any control over the imported data, so I can't fix the spreadsheet, much as I'd like to. I'd also like to avoid specific hackery in the import function itself (e.g. using TransferSpreadsheet instead). Goal is to use the same approach to bringing in data, just ignore the bits which don't work.

Also should point out that it is appropriate for non-date values here to be discarded. Importing as Text is ideally something I'd like to avoid, since it'll cause all sorts of other errors further down the chain.

EDIT: Added the stipulation, 2003. I should also point out that the version of the .Net framework installed in the environment does not include (or doesnt appear to include) an ACE.12.0 provider.

Edit 2: As requested, here's a (slightly cleaned) version of the SQL I'm executing. Please note it's not the exact query, but running this on the same spreadsheet causes the same issues:

```
SELECT 
    CStr(Nz([Notes], "")), 
    [ID],
    [Date]
INTO
    [;DATABASE=C:\DatabaseTarget.Mdb].[tblImport]
FROM
    [Excel 8.0;Database=C:\ExcelSheet.xls].[sheet1$]
WHERE
    [ID] IS NOT NULL
```

The issue can be seen by taking out the `INTO` clause, and looking at the values for `[Date]`. If any of them are `#Num!` Then even doing the following results in `#Num!`s for all Test1-5, which rather demonstrates the issue.:

```
SELECT 
    CStr(Nz([Notes], '')), 
    [ID],
    CStr(Nz([Date],'')) As [Test1],
    IsError([Date]) As [Test2],
    IsDate([Date]) As [Test3],
    IsNull([Date]) As [Test4],
    IIf(True, 1, [Date]) As [Test5],
FROM
    [Excel 8.0;Database=C:\ExcelSheet.xls].[sheet1$]
WHERE
    [ID] IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Testing for `IsNull()` looks like it should work. For the Excel data...

```
ID  ActivityDescription ActivityDate
1   activity_1          2013-05-12
2   activity_2          2013-05-13
3   activity_3          2013-05-14
4   activity_4          2013-05-15
5   activity_5          2013-05-16
6   activity_6          2013-05-17
7   activity_7          2013-05-18
8   activity_8          2013-05-19
9   activity_9          2013-05-20
10  activity_10         2013-05-21
11  activity_11         2013-05-22
12  activity_12         2013-05-23
13  activity_13         oops!
14  activity_14         2013-05-25
15  activity_15         2013-05-26
```

...the following Access VBA code...

```
Sub adoTest()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection, rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open _
        "Provider=Microsoft.JET.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=C:\Users\Public\xlsTest.xls;" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES"";"
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.Open "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", con
Do While Not rst.EOF
    Debug.Print _
            Format(rst("ID").Value, "00") & _
            "  " & _
            IIf(IsNull(rst("ActivityDate").Value), "<NULL>", rst("ActivityDate").Value)
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

...produces this:

```
01  2013-05-12
02  2013-05-13
03  2013-05-14
04  2013-05-15
05  2013-05-16
06  2013-05-17
07  2013-05-18
08  2013-05-19
09  2013-05-20
10  2013-05-21
11  2013-05-22
12  2013-05-23
13  <NULL>
14  2013-05-25
15  2013-05-26
```

This shows that `IsNull()` recognizes the "bad" date value as `Null` and substitutes the text `<NULL>` instead.

Depending on the context, the `Nz()` function might also prove useful.

Comment: Might well work under ACE, but unfortunately, I'm stuck with JET, as this is Office 2003. Sorry, should have specified.

That said, not sure I've used IsNull() To test or gone straight to Nz. The situation is somewhat odd, since some text data kicking around in these fields does get correctly interpretted, but some doesn't.

Comment: @tobriand I just tested the code using Jet and I got exactly the same results. (I have updated my answer.)

Comment: I'll try it in a few minutes and see whether it fixes it. Am I right in thinking that not wrapping your data in IsNull also produces a #Num! error?

Comment: @tobriand No, if I just try to `Debug.Print` `rst("ActivityDate").Value` that one entry is empty, not `#Num!`. However, I *do* see `#Num!` if I create an Access linked table into the Excel sheet and then open that linked table in datasheet view.

Comment: I've now tried an `IsNull` approach with the same result. I think #Num! is a very fussy error type compared to others. Have found a workaround though! Fire the same query through DAO with errors turned off, and any data it couldn't bring in gets replaced with Null, which is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The #Num! errors appear to be raised by the provider before they hit most of the error approaches that can be used for error handling in queries. Sticking with ADO seems prone to failure.

However, testing my query in DAO (without the `INTO` clause to just produce a recordset) did produce valid sata, so I figured it might be worth seeing if DAO can deal with a query to an OLEDB recordsource. Turns out it can!

Therefore final code looks something like

```
On Error Resume Next
cmdFirstTry.Execute '' Includes fields which are pulled through as #Num! errors
Select Case Err.Number
    Case 0
        On Error Goto ErrorHandler
    Case &H80040E14
        '' Failed in this manner; Try with DAO
        On Error Goto ErrorHandler
        CurrentDb.Execute strSQL
    Case Else
        lngErrNum = Err.Number
        strErrDesc = Err.Description
        On Error Goto ErrorHandler
        Err.Raise lngErrNum, , strErrDesc
End Select
```

For my needs, this does the job, but I won't accept as the answer for a few days yet, in case there really is an elegant approach.

Comment: What is the SQL statement you are executing?

Comment: I've added a cut-down version of the issue above. The SQL statement executes fine on DAO, even without specifying more detail for Provider etc. However, I get comparable results on ADODB, hence the question in the first place!